# NFC APIs in BlackBerry 10 Webworks(HTML5) Platform?

Tags: nfc, blackberry-10

Hi friends I am new to Blackberry 10 Development Platform. Are  there some ways to Invoke NFC APIs in BlackBerry 10 Webworks(HTML5) Platform?

Such as Reading Tags or Writing Tags.

Answer (score 2):

The BlackBerry WebWorks platform does not currently support NFC API's. These will be included into a future release.

For more information on existing API's, visit https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/bb10_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered this sample application on github that may help you to further your investigation
https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Community-Samples/tree/master/nfc